# Dirichlet Process vs Hierarchical Dirichlet Process: coupling among transitions on infinite HMM

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, hidden-markov-model, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

I'm new to nonparametric Bayesian, and I am reading a paper about [beam sampling for the infinite hidden Markov model](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1390156.1390293). In the paper, it is mentioned that since there is no coupling among the transitions if one uses the Dirichlet process, we need to have a hierarchical Dirichlet process instead of a Dirichlet process for the hidden Markov model.
I am having a hard time understanding the intuition behind the need for the coupling and how the hierarchical process introduces this coupling. I went on and read some other papers ([Dirichlet Process](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Eteh/research/npbayes/Teh2010a.pdf), [Hierarchical Dirichlet Proces](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/206-Exch/Papers/hierarchical_dirichlet.pdf)), but still, I cannot grab the concept it yet. Any reading suggestions or explanations will be helpful.